# Store passwords accessible

Tags: sql, security, storage, password-encryption

I want to write a library for my media files. Since I am using a few SAMBA-shares i was wondering how I should save the passwords, since I need them to access the share. Is there any other possibility to store them than just plain text?

I am using postgresql for the data. The end-product will be a web app.

The difference to other password saving questions is, that i need to send the password to other services. That's the reason why I can't save hashes.

Comment: then don't use hashes and use for example public/private keys to encrypt and decrypt them

Comment: @Aitch sorry, I forgot to mention that this will be a webapp, kinda like plex media server.

Comment: doesn't matter. you have one component which has the public key and encrypts the password. another component has the private key and then decrypts the password and sends it. You just don't want to store plain-text passwords.

Comment: @Aitch well, i tried finding a solution that'd be easy to use but i can't store or read files on the client side. and saving private and public key on the server wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the NT hash you should still be able to [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) authenticate to Samba. This isn't a bulletproof solution since [the NT hash is as good as the password itself to servers that accept NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash), but assuming that your Samba server is well-protected on a private network it's still an improvement. Among other things, it makes it less likely that someone stealing your password database can use the contents to compromise users' accounts on *other* systems where they may use the same password.